# ST_Contains not returning a correct result

Tags: postgis, spatial-join

I'm trying to do a spatial join between a table that stores locations of photos and the table with names and geometries of countries and the table containing locations of major cities.

For example here we have a multupolygon of Australia and I've confirmed that it's a valid geometry:

[image]

and we have a point that is clearly in Australia:

[image]

If I run a simple query:

```sql
select c."name"
from country c
where st_contains(c.geometry, st_geomfromtext('POINTZ(-37.56977080555556 144.89031980555555 265)', 4326))
```

...I get an empty return from the query. I've also tried `st_within` and `st_intersects` but neither of those return any result.

I tried a spatial join, and it works correctly if I only merge with the `City` table:

```sql
select i."path", i."timestamp", c."name"
from image i
join city c
    on ST_DWithin(i."location", c."location", 50000, true)
```

but if I add `Country` table to the mix, I get only a handful of results and even those are all wrong:

```sql
select i."path", i."timestamp", c."name" , x."name" 
from image i
join city c
    on ST_DWithin(i."location", c."location", 50000, true)
join country x
    on ST_Contains(x.geometry, i."location")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. As I said, all geometries are valid and DBeaver correctly interprets the geometry in SRID 4326.

**EDIT:**
Ok I found the issue. For some reason it contains doesn't like the order of coordinates I have.

This (lat, lon):

```
'POINT(144.89031980555555 -37.56977080555556)'
```

doesn't work, but for some reason

```
'POINT(-37.56977080555556 144.89031980555555 )'
```

Gives a correct result.

Comment: I wonder if it's not a limit story... and if you tested the functions: st_Covers and st_CoveredBy?

Comment: @fcka, tried these functions now too with the same result.

Comment: It isn't for some reason - postgis operates that way https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html

Comment: Your initial Point WKT is in (Lat Lon) order, which is simply not what PostGIS expects. Your edit also confuses the order again.

Comment: Please cut/paste your answer from the area reserved for your question into the area reserved for answers.

Comment: POINT(X,Y,Z,M) is the order for point coordinates in postgis.  In case all your coordinates are flipped, you can use st_flipcoordinates, which will swap the x and y coordinates.